# Page numbers of two section not aligning

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I'm relatively new to LaTex, and I'm having trouble with the alignment of page numbers for just two of my sections. My preamble is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, left=3cm, top = 1cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
```

and within the `document`, I'm using the following commands:

```
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

after the title page, and

```
\section{Conclusion}
...
\section*{Acknowledgements}
...
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

but the `toc` ends up looking like this:

[image]

Also, even though I've used `\begin{thebibliography}{99}`, the section is called References when I compile, but still Bibliography in the `toc`.

Why are the page numbers for the Acknowledgements and the Bibliography not aligned on the right, with the others? And why is it "Bibliography", when the section compiles as "References"?

Comment: Your code doesn't explain how your unumbered section appears in the table of contents.

Comment: You're loading `hyperref` in the middle of the preamble, which is not recommended

Comment: as @Bernard stresses you are not telling us how you push the starred section Acnowkledgement to the toc file, and same for the bibliography. Look out for `\addcontentsline{toc}...` lines in your code, or extra packages in preamble.

Comment: Ah! I used \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} and changed it to  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}, which fixed it. I didn't know that was the problem, thank you for your comments.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, why is loading `hyperref` in the middle of the preamble no recommended?

Comment: @Jim421616: Because `hyperref` does a lot of redefinitions concerning links and ToC ... and you're are in trouble with your ToC, aren't you?

Comment: Gotcha...I just found in the `hyperref` doc that it should be loaded last. I didn't realize that, thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: The code you provided does not reveal why the behaviour occurs. Please provide a minimal working example. The question cannot be answered right now.